# SnowFlake -> How to insert a date (timestamp) from a stage to a table?

Tags: timestamp, format, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

SnowFlake -> How to insert a date (timestamp) from a stage to a table?

For example :
I have the following flat file

```
FILE.CSV

ID; DATE ; TEXT
6908402;16-06-2022 13:28:52;DAWEAWEADA
6908403;16-06-2022 ; asdasda
6908404;16-06-2022 13:28:53;helloTest
6908405;16-06-2022 13:28:54;hello%%$%
6908406;16-06-2022 13:28:55;
```

I create the format that will contain the file

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT DBO.CSV_SEMICOLON
  type = 'CSV'
  field_delimiter = ';'
  skip_header = 1
  encoding=UTF8   
  ;
```

I assign the format to the new stage

```
CREATE STAGE IF NOT EXISTS DBO.STG_FILE file_format = DBO.CSV_SEMICOLON;
```

I insert the information to the stage

```
REMOVE  @STG_FILE;
put file://D:\TEST\FILE.CSV @STG_FILE;
```

Once the information is inserted into the @stage_file, I want to insert the information into the table.

**This is where I have problems since the $2 column of the stage that comes from the file can come either just the date or with the time** , I don't know what I should do to be able to insert this value

the definition of the destination fields are these

```
Table : dbo.T_FILE
       ID = VARCHAR(255)
       DATE = TIMESTAMPNTZ
       TEXT = VARCHAR(5000)
```

```
-------------
-INSERT TABLE
-------------
INSERT INTO DBO.T_FILE(ID, "DATE", TEXT)

SELECT $1, $2, $3, 
FROM @STG_FILE WHERE $3 <> ''
```

Thank you very much for your advice

Comment: What is the error or issue that you get from Snowflake when you try and run the INSERT?  Have you tried using a COPY statement, instead?  If you only have the 2 different format types, you could use a CASE statement in your SELECT based on the length of $2 and then explicitly format the datetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Target table -

```
create temporary table T_FILE (id varchar(255), date_1 TIMESTAMPNTZ, text_1 VARCHAR(5000))
```

Below Query -

```
insert into T_FILE select $1,COALESCE(TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP_LTZ($2,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),try_TO_TIMESTAMP_LTZ
($2,'dd-mm-yyyy')),$3 from @stg_file;
```

will insert following -

```
select * from t_file;
```

| ID | DATE_1 | TEXT_1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6908402 | 2022-06-16 13:28:52.000 | DAWEAWEADA |
| 6908403 | 2022-06-16 00:00:00.000 | asdasda |
| 6908404 | 2022-06-16 13:28:53.000 | helloTest |
| 6908405 | 2022-06-16 13:28:54.000 | hello%%$% |
| 6908406 | 2022-06-16 13:28:55.000 | NULL |

After reading from the source file given below -

```
select $1,$2,$3 from @stg_file;
```

| $1 | $2 | $3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6908402 | 16-06-2022 13:28:52 | DAWEAWEADA |
| 6908403 | 16-06-2022 | asdasda |
| 6908404 | 16-06-2022 13:28:53 | helloTest |
| 6908405 | 16-06-2022 13:28:54 | hello%%$% |
| 6908406 | 16-06-2022 13:28:55 | NULL |

Comment: Perfect!! It is very close to what I need, the only drawback I see is that the HEURES shows it to me with a delay of 3 hours.

that is to say like this = 16-06-2022 09:28:52;

Comment: This is to show inserting value with different time-formats using conversion function. You can choose conversion function or time settings at session level as per your requirements - Refer here for more details on conversion functions - https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_timestamp.html#to-timestamp-to-timestamp

Comment: Perfect it worked with the -> TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP.
Thank you very much